# Chrome applies userstyles (custom.css) on the fly even when edited in external editor, how can I use this mechanism for webdev?

Tags: css, google-chrome, customization

So chrome auto updates the changes made to the `C:\Users\*\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\User StyleSheets\Custom.css`. It's great because I can choose my favorite editor and free me from any browser-integrated tools for css manipulation.

But it only works for that specific file. I know it can't be used directly to edit server-side css even when I'm working on a `localhost` server. But is there any other way I can use this sweet mechanism, perhaps manually telling chrome to look for a specific css file and use that as an alternate `Custom.css`?

EDIT: Importing doesn't work either i think.. none of these rule seem to have any effect

```
@import "stylish.1misc.css";            //in the same dir as Custom.css
@import url("stylish.1misc.css");
@import url("http://localhost/.my/stylish.2img.css");
@import url("file:///D:/.localhost/.my/stylish.1misc.css");
```

[related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13482157/why-cant-i-import-from-chromes-userstylesheet-custom-css)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Chrome Developer Tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/) to do just [that](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/resources) and several other things. Like Also editing and [hot swapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_swapping) Javascript.

There is a plethora of [examples](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nOEw9iiopwI) you can find by doing a quick search on google or youtube.

Here is an example of hot swapping some CSS on a popular site, making the `font-size` much larger.

[image: Me gustan las tortugas]

The changes can be saved locally (to the cache folder I suppose) or you can choose to save them somewhere else.

The Changes aren't persistent however, refreshing the page will cause all the changes to be lost, but if you want to make the changes permanent for sites you don't own, you can paste those changes to the Chrome User Stylesheet; or you your own projects you can save your changes locally. For this last case there are plenty of good practices and advice on the links provided above.