# Why can't I @import from Chrome's userstylesheet Custom.css?

Tags: css, google-chrome, customization

I was hoping to import other css files from withing the Chrome's custom stylesheet `C:\Users\*\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\User StyleSheets\Custom.css` but it doesn't seem to be working. I have a `stylish.1misc.css` and a `stylish.2img.css` inside the same dir as above. Also with symlinks I've set them up on my localserver as `http://localhost/.my/stylish.2img.css` but none of the @import rules seem to be working

```
@import "stylish.1misc.css";
@import url("stylish.1misc.css");
@import url("http://localhost/.my/stylish.2img.css");
@import url("file:///D:/.localhost/.my/stylish.1misc.css");
```

Why wont it import?

[related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13429928/chrome-applies-userstyles-custom-css-on-the-fly-even-when-edited-in-external-e)

Comment: Pretty much every browser other than IE will not let you link to content that's part of the user's file system.  It's considered a security vulnerability (IE considers it a *feature*).

Answer (score 1):

Although I am having the same issue with Chrome as well, but the statement concerning inclusion of local stylesheets in case of every browser with the exception of IE lacks merit. Opera, Firefox, and Safari all allow inclusion of local stylesheets. Safari and Opera even allow users to use stylesheets which are located anywhere on their hard disks. As the process of instructing a web browser to use a local stylesheet requires a local user's involvement, hence the chances of violating the security remain minimal to almost non existent.

As CSS files have to conform to strict rules, hence that probably provides another reason for making it possible for users to choose local CSS files from any directory on the hard disk, as browsers simply stop parsing the file in case it does not conform to predefined rules and standards.